# Martingale regularization with right continuous filtration

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

The standard textbook presentation of the Doob Regularization Theorem for a martingale $(X_t, \mathcal{F}_t)$ assumes that the filtration satisfies the usual conditions.  It is clear that the assumption of right continuity of the filtration is critical (both in showing the adaptedness of the modification $X^+_t = \lim_{q \to t^+} X_t$ as well as showing the martingale property of $X^+$ using the Levy Downward Theorem).  On the other hand, it is clear that the assumption of completeness is stronger than necessary for all we really need to assume is that $\mathcal{F}_0$ contains the null event where the limits $\lim_{q \to t^+} X_q$ and $\lim_{q \to t^-}X_q$ fail to exist: this assumption being used to conclude that $X^+$ is $\mathcal{F}$-adapted.

The question is that I occasionally run into scenarios in which the existence of a cadlag version is asserted with only an assumption of right continuity in the filtration.  This is not uncommon in Girsanov Theory in which the usual conditions cause subtle problems.  For example on pg. 325 of Revuz and Yor we have the statement "These (classes of) random variables form a $(\mathcal{F}^0_t, P)$-martingale and since $(\mathcal{F}^0_t)$ is right continuous, we may choose $D_t$ within its $P$-equivalence class so that the resulting process $D$ is a $(\mathcal{F}^0_t)$-adapted martingale almost every path of which is cadlag...".  There are other examples that I can quote (even Kallenberg is a bit slippery on this point).

Without some a priori knowledge that right and left limits exist prior to modification I don't see how this can be true; we can certainly modify to a cadlag process within the $P$-equivalence class but without further assumptions on the filtration we destroy $\mathcal{F}$-adaptedness.  Is there something that I am missing here?

Comment: @ David Blair : On the other hand for Markovian process (even Feller if not mistaken) it suffices to have the completion of the initial sigma algebra to imply the right continuity of the filtration (You can look at P. Protter's book where this point is proved). Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have the result that you are looking for. It is called "Föllmer's lemma" (theorem 2.44 chapter II section 5 in the book "Semimartingale Theory and Stochastic Calculus" by Gang Wang, Jia-An Yan and here is how it goes :

(of course you are given a stochastic basis with no particular assumptions regarding the regularity of the filtration)

Let's be given $(X_t)_{t\in \mathbb{R}^+}$ a supermartingale (resp. martingale) and $D$ a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Then there exists a process $\bar{X}_t$ such that the following four points hold :

1-$(\bar{X}_t)_{t\in \mathbb{R}^+}$ is right continuous for almost all $\omega$, for any $t\in \mathbb{R}^+$ ; $\bar{X_t}(\omega)=\lim_{(s\in D,s \searrow \searrow t )}X_s(\omega)$.

2-for almost all $\omega$, for any $t>0$,

$\bar{X}_{t_-}(\omega)=\lim_{(s\in \mathbb{R}^+,s \nearrow \nearrow t )}\bar{X}_s(\omega)$ exists and is finite. And we have moreover :

$\bar{X}_{t_-}(\omega)=\lim_{(s\in D,s \nearrow \nearrow t )}X_s(\omega)$

3- For all $t\in\mathbb{R}^+$ :

$X_t\geq \mathbb{E}[\bar{X}_t|\mathcal{F}_t]$ (resp. equality for the martingale case)

4- $(\bar{X}_t)_{t\in \mathbb{R}^+}$ is a $\mathcal{F}_+$-supermartingale (resp. martingale). Where $\mathcal{F}_+$ is the right continuous filtration generated by the filtration $\mathcal{F}$.

As you can notice there is no completion of the filtration at time 0 by the negligible sets.

Comment: This is part of the Doob regularization theorem.  The germ of the modification to the filtration lurks here in the almost sure modifiers on the right continuity and existence of limits assertions.  In most presentations that I've seen one goes a step further to get an everywhere cadlag process by defining it to be zero where the limits don't exist; this requires the addition of a null set to the filtration.  I now see that Revuz and Yor only ask for cadlag paths almost surely so it appears addition of null set is not required.  I'll check details and that we get a version in this case.

Comment: Off the top of my head I am failing to see how to define $\overline{X}$ on the event where the limits don't exist while keeping it adapted to a general $\mathcal{F}$.  I don't have access to the book (and Google books conveniently elides exactly the pages where this is proved!); it'd be great if you could help me see how this is done. Otherwise off to the library...

Comment: @David Blair : I'll try to give the proof of the theorem later (I dont have the book with right now). But those authors are sometimes hard to understand (the translation from chinese is not always very good I believe). Although there is a reference at the page of the theorem it leads to no address in the reference part of the book so I don't know which paper of Föllmer is really the source of the theorem, as they give the proof this is not too serious problem but if their proof lacks rigour in some points I won't be able to check with the source. Best regards

Comment: I think this works.  Just define $A_t$ to be the event that the limits $\lim_{q \to t^+} X_q$ exist.  Let $\overline{X}_t = 1_{A_t} \lim_{q \to t^+} X_q$ and note that $\overline{X}$ is $\mathcal{F}^+$ adapted.  If we let $A = \cap_t A_t$ then $\overline{X}$ agrees on $A$ with the everywhere cadlag version $\tilde{X}_t = 1_{A} \lim_{q \to t^+} X_q$ which is a $\overline{\mathcal{F}}^+$ (sub)martingale (from the "standard textbook" proof).  Since $A$ has probability 1 it follows that $\overline{X}$ is a version of $X$, is almost surely cadlag and is a $\mathcal{F}^+$ (sub)martingale.  Thanks!

Comment: @ David Blair : Your argument seems too work but I'll edit my answer to include the proof given by the authors. Best regards

Comment: This might be off topic, but why is everyone refering to $ \bar{X}$ as a modification of $X$? The value of X at some t might not be equal to its limit from any side. Hence $X\ne \bar{X}$ a.s for such $ t$ and thus is not a modification. If we assume that $\mathbb{E}X(t)$ is right-continous it is a modification tho imo. Or is there something that I am missing?